# Array instead of object from json_encode with recursive method

Tags: php, arrays, json, recursion

I have the following method that I use to recursively build my php arrays then turn them into a json string:

```
protected function stringKeyToMultArray(&$newarr, $keys, $value) {
    if(count($keys) > 1) {
        $key = array_shift($keys);

        if(!isset($newarr[$key]) || !is_array($newarr[$key])) {
            $newarr[$key] = array();
        }

        $this->stringKeyToMultArray($newarr[$key], $keys, $value);
    } else {
        $newarr[array_shift($keys)] = $value;
    }
}
```

EDIT: This is how it is called:

```
$path_arr = [];
foreach ($product_row['fields'] as $field) {
    //gets the path for this field like pathto/field
    $strpath = $tags[$field['id']]['str_path'];
    $paths = explode('/', $strpath);
    $this->stringKeyToMultArray($path_arr, $paths, $field['value']);
}
```

Then after this is simply json_encode it like json_encode($path_arr)
END EDIT
The issue is the formatting if it gets to a second level should use an array to wrap the parts. So what I am getting now is:

```
{  
    "product_title":"Test Title",
    "ASIN":"1234567890",
    "codes":{  
        "type":"UPC",
        "number":"030878249270"
    },
    "quantity":"1"
}
```

What I need is the following:

```
{  
    "product_title":"Test Title",
    "ASIN":"1234567890",
    "codes":[
        {  
        "type":"UPC",
        "number":"030878249270"
        }
    ],
    "quantity":"1"
}
```

Any ideas on how I could do this with the recursive method?

Comment: Do you have sample input that is incorrectly encoding?

Comment: json_encode will give you an object.. if you want an array/associative array, use json_decode. That being said, I don't even see json_encode being used here.

Comment: "if it gets to a second level should use an object to wrap the parts" - but what you're showing after "What I need is the following:" is an object wrapped in _an array_.

Comment: @VolkerK Sorry just edited, I need it wrapped in an array.

Comment: `$strpath = $tags[$field....` is that really $strpath or `$jetpath`? And if it's not $jetpath, then where does `$jetpath` come from?

Comment: @VolkerK Its really strpath

Comment: I've created an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) of what I believe is the current status at https://3v4l.org/Tk6JN . The main problem is that your parser is stateless, it has no idea if an element belongs to one array or another. Can there be multiple $field['id'] with the same value in $product_row['fields'] ? E.g. leading to `code:[{"type":"UPC",number:"123"}, {"type":"UPC","number:"567"}]` ?

Comment: @VolkerK it looks correct and what I am getting is the same response. However I am trying to format it to be accepted to a certain api. and anything at the second level should be wrapped in an array, hence needing the square brackets around the codes object.

Comment: No, the parent will only have one type and one number, there will never be two objects with that information for a product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the (very) specific conditions stated in the question and the comments:

```
protected function stringKeyToMultArray(&$newarr, $keys, $value) {
    if (count($keys) > 1) {
        $key = array_shift($keys);
        if ( !isset($newarr[$key]) || !is_array($newarr[$key])) {
            $newarr[$key] = array(array());
        }
        $this->stringKeyToMultArray($newarr[$key][0], $keys, $value);

    } else {
        $newarr[array_shift($keys)] = $value;
    }
}
```

see https://3v4l.org/4Hpek

Comment: Given the awesomeness of the answer... this works perfectly.